# Antiforgery Token Cookie Not Appearing in Request Headers Only in when Embeded in Iframe

Tags: cookies, iframe, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

I'm trying to embed a simple web app that will POST user input that is running asp.net Core 2.0 into an iframe.  The problem I am having is that while embedded, the request headers that are being generated lack the cookie header that contains the .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.[token].  It is being generated as expected outside of the iframe.

This is causing a 400 error because the post is unable to validate the token.

Request Headers generated outside of iframe:
[Request Headers: NO IFRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUuQm.png)

Request Headers generated inside of iframe:
[Request Headers: INSIDE IFRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHCQB.png)

Has anyone had this issue with the antiforgery token library?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the SameSite property on the cookie class for the antiforgery options needs to be set to None for this to work:

`services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});`

Comment: this helped me out a lot. do you foresee any security issues with setting this to none.

Comment: The security risk is that other sites would be able to post to your page hijacking the cookies the client already has.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Flyingmartini didn't worked for me, I needed to set these properties as well:

```
            services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
            });
```