# Anti-Forgery error on IIS C# MVC embedded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, embedded, antiforgerytoken

I've got a WebApplication (C# .Net MVC + IIS) where everything works as usual.
However one of my clients requested to embed my WebApplication in his Website through iFrame.

The problem is: everytime I try to log in (submiting a form) I get this message: 'The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.'.
My view does has '__RequestVerificationToken'.

To be honest, it makes sense to get this kinda error running my web application on iFrame, but I do want to make this happen and I've tried so many things without success.

**My View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @data_animation = "true" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.ReturnUrl)
```

**My Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel viewModel)
```

**Web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="TesteAbc" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" protection="All" path="/" timeout="180" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Are you seeing errors in the console?  [Is this the same issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099181/asp-net-core-antiforgery-denying-form-submission-from-iframe)

Comment: I've got: error 500 (from IIS on iFrame) and a bunch issues/warnings about 'SameSite' attribute - maybe there is some tip/trick here

Answer (score 2):

Solution was settings attribute SameSite in httpCookies at web.config

```
<httpCookies sameSite="[Strict|Lax|None|Unspecified]" requireSSL="[true|false]" />
```

**in my case**:

sameSite="None"

requireSSL="true"

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.